# Integral of product of CDF and PDF 0f standard normal distribution

Tags: integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

> Show that:
>   $$\int_{y=0}^\infty \frac{8y}{\sigma}\phi\left(\frac{y}{\sigma}\right)\Phi\left(\frac{y}{\sigma}\right)\ dy\ -\int_{y=0}^\infty \frac{4y}{\sigma}\phi\left(\frac{y}{\sigma}\right)\ dy\ =\frac{2}{\sqrt \pi}\sigma $$ 
>   where $\phi(.)$ and $\Phi(.)$ i.e. normal pdf and cdf.

I tried by letting $t=\frac{1}{\sigma}$ then $y=t\sigma$ and $dt=\frac{1}{\sigma}dy.$ The equation became $$\int_{0}^\infty 8t\sigma\phi(t)\Phi(t)\ dt\ -\int_{0}^\infty 4t\sigma\phi(t)\ dt\ =\frac{2}{\sqrt \pi}\sigma $$
First I worked with $$\int_{0}^\infty 8t\sigma\phi(t)\Phi(t)\ dt =8\sigma\int_{0}^\infty t\Phi(t)d(\Phi(t))$$

Let $u=t$ $du=dt,$ $dv=\Phi(t)d(\Phi(t))$ $$v=\frac{1}{2}\Phi^2(t)=t\frac{1}{2}\Phi^2(t)\rvert_{0}^\infty-\int_{0}^\infty \frac{1}{2}\Phi^2(t)\ dt\\
=\frac{t}{2}[\Phi^2(\infty)-\Phi^2(0)]-\int_{0}^\infty \frac{1}{2}\Phi^2(t)\ dt$$
But then I'm stuck here. Please help me. Perhaps there's a different way to prove this, either by analytic or numerical. 
thanks

Comment: With some cream on top?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: actually i did some effort by trying to use partial integral but still don't get the answer, @JoséCarlosSantos thanks for your suggestions

Comment: We can't see the effort if you don't post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**0.** To be proven:
$$\int_{0}^\infty 8t\varphi(t)\Phi(t)dt-\int_{0}^\infty 4t\varphi(t)dt =\frac2{\sqrt \pi} $$
that is,

> $$I=\frac1{4\sqrt\pi}$$

where

> $$I=\int_{0}^\infty t\varphi(t)\left(\Phi(t)-\tfrac12\right)\ dt$$

**1.** By definition of $\varphi$ as the PDF of a standard normal random variable $X$, $$I=E\left(X\left(\Phi(X)-\tfrac12\right):X>0\right)$$
**2.** For every $x>0$, for some  standard normal random variable $Y$ independent of $X$, $$\Phi(x)-\tfrac12=P(x>Y>0)$$ hence $$I=E\left(X:X>Y>0\right)$$
**3.** For every $x$, $$x\varphi(x)=-\varphi'(x)$$ hence, for every $y$, $$E(X:X>y)=\int_y^\infty x\varphi(x)dx=\varphi(y)$$ which yields $$I=E(\varphi(Y):Y>0)=\int_0^\infty\varphi^2(y)dy$$
**4.** Finally, $$\varphi^2(y)=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\varphi(\sqrt2 y)$$ hence the change of variable $z=\sqrt2 y$ yields $$I=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^\infty\varphi(z)\frac{dz}{\sqrt2}=\frac1{2\sqrt\pi}P(X>0)=\frac1{4\sqrt\pi}$$