# Integral of product of standard normal CDF and PDF

Tags: integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

> Show that:
>   $$\int_{0}^\infty 8t^2\sigma^2\phi(t)\Phi(t)\ dt\ -\int_{0}^\infty 4t^2\sigma^2\phi(t)\ dt\ =\left(1+\frac{2}{\pi}\right)\sigma^2 $$
>   where $\phi(.)$ and $\Phi(.)$ i.e. normal pdf and cdf.

I've tried as the answer has been given on 
[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2589784/integral-of-product-of-cdf-and-pdf-0f-standard-normal-distribution)

this what I've tried

$$8\sigma^2\left(\int_{0}^\infty t^2\phi(t)\left(\Phi(t)-\tfrac12\right)\ dt\right)$$
Suppose:
$$I=\int_{0}^\infty t^2\phi(t)\left(\Phi(t)-\tfrac12\right)\ dt$$
By definition of $\phi$ as the PDF of a standard normal random variable $X$,
$$I=E\left(X^2\left(\Phi(X)-\tfrac12\right):X>0\right)$$

For every $x>0$, for some  standard normal random variable $Y$ independent of $X$, $$\Phi(x)-\tfrac12=P(x>Y>0)$$ hence $$I=E\left(X^2:X>Y>0\right)$$

for every $y$, $$E(X^2:X>y)=\int_y^\infty x^2\phi(x)dx=\int_y^\infty -x\phi'(x)dx=\int_\infty^y x\phi'(x)dx=x\phi(x)\rvert_\infty^{y}-\int_\infty^y\phi(x)dx = y\phi(y)-\Phi(y)$$ which yields $$I=E(y\phi(y)-\Phi(y):Y>0)=\int_0^\infty \left(y\phi(y)-\Phi(y)\right)\phi(y)dy =\int_0^\infty y\phi^2(y)dy-\int_0^\infty \Phi(y)\phi(y)dy $$

I'm stuck here. Please help me.

Thank you

Comment: Starting from where you stopped, now use the (already used on the other page) fact that $$\varphi^2(y)=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\varphi(\sqrt2 y)$$ and the identity $$\varphi(y)\Phi(y)=\left(\tfrac12\Phi(y)^2\right)'$$

Comment: @Did thank you for your hint,this is what I did with your hint
$$\int_{0}^\infty y\varphi^2(y)dy=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\int_0^\infty z\varphi(z)\frac{dz}{\sqrt2}=\frac1{2\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^\infty z\varphi(z) dz=\frac1{4\pi}$$

and 
$$\int_0^\infty\varphi(y)\Phi(y)dy=\int_0^\infty \left(\frac1{2}\Phi(y)^2\right)'dy=\frac1{2}\Phi(y)^2=\frac1{2}\int_{-\infty}^x\varphi^2(y)dy=\frac1{2}\int_{-\infty}^x\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\varphi(\sqrt{2}y)dy=\frac1{{2}\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^x\varphi(z)\frac{dz}{\sqrt2}=\frac1{{4}\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^x \varphi(z) dz$$
But I'm stuck here.

Comment: @Did Could you help me to check what's wrong and what should I do next?

Comment: The second "=" sign in the second computation in your comment is wrong. Please revise.

Comment: @Did I don't know whether this is true or not. I want to show you the revise that I did,
$$\int_0^\infty \Phi(y)\phi(y)dy=\int_0^\infty \left(\frac{1}{2}\Phi(y)^2\right)'dy=\int_{-\infty}^0 -\left(\frac{1}{2}\Phi(y)^2\right)'dy=-\left(\frac{1}{2}\Phi(0)^2\right)=-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}[1+erf\left(\frac{0}{\sqrt{2}}\right)]\right)^2=-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}[1+erf(0)]\right)^2=-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)=-\frac{1}{8}$$
I will be grateful if you can send me a reply

Comment: Why the twists and turns? Simply use $$\int_0^\infty g'(y)dy=g(\infty)-g(0)$$

Comment: @Did If I using,
$$\int_0^\infty g'(y)dy=g(\infty)-g(0)$$
I get,
$$\int_0^\infty \left(\frac{1}{2}\Phi(y)^2\right)dy=\frac{1}{2}(\Phi(\infty)^2-\Phi(0)^2)=\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2\right)=\frac{3}{8}$$
and I return to the last equation in my question
$$\int_0^\infty y\phi^2(y)dy-\int_0^\infty \Phi(y)\phi(y)dy=\frac{1}{4\pi}-\frac{3}{8}=\frac{2-3\pi}{8\pi}$$
which not yields $\left(1+\frac{2}{\pi}\right)$ if $8\left(\frac{2-3\pi}{8\pi}\right)$.

Comment: If I use as in my previous comment,
$$\int_0^\infty y\phi^2(y)dy-\int_0^\infty \Phi(y)\phi(y)dy=\frac{1}{4\pi}-\left(-\frac{1}{8}\right)=\frac{2+\pi}{8\pi}$$
which yields $\left(1+\frac{2}{\pi}\right)$ if $8\left(\frac{2+\pi}{8\pi}\right)$. But I don't know if the concept that I use in my previous comment was right or wrong